# GUI action listeners for each tab in a tabbed pane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

I am fairly new to java so bear with me please, basically, below I have a tabbed pane for each of the four rooms in the rooms Arraylist, and I am creating buttons in each tab depending how many lights each room has, How can I associate the buttons in each tab with a specified the rooms?. So like when I click the light button in the Room 1 tab, the event listener knows that the button belongs to the room1?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MasterGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public MasterGUI(){

}

public void DisplayFrame(){
    ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;
    rooms = Building.getRoomList();

    JFrame master = new JFrame("Solar Master Control Panel"); 
    master.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = master.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel tmpPanel;

    for(int x = 0; x < rooms.size(); x++){
        tmpPanel = new JPanel();
        String roomName = rooms.get(x).getName();
        int id = rooms.get(x).getId();
        tabbedPane.addTab(roomName + " Room " + id, tmpPanel);
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < rooms.size(); x++){
        for(int i = 0; i < rooms.get(x).roomLights.size(); i++){
            int num = i + 1;
            ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(x)).add(new JButton("Light" + num));
        }
    }

    master.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    master.setSize(800, 600);
    content.add(tabbedPane);
    master.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}
```

Comment: A wrapper class could work, or a `HashMap<JButton, Room>`.

Comment: Java has a [for-each loop](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html) that would mean you don't have to do all the `get(x)` calls. You can also add the buttons to the panel when you first create it, instead of one loop to make the panels and another loop to add the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, you need to add the `ActionListener` to the button so it will be called when the button is clicked.

```
...
JButton button = new JButton("Light" + num);
button.addActionListener(this);
((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(x)).add(button);
...
```

As far as differentiating between which button was clicked, there are two main ways to address this. The first is to use `getSource()` on the `ActionEvent` to get a reference to the object that triggered the event. You can use this to decide how you want to proceed further. The other option is to have `MasterGUI` **not** implement `ActionListener`. Instead, make a unique `ActionListener` for each button that immediately know what action needs to occur when it was called. The first option makes it easier to register listeners, but requires more work in the handler to determine the source. I prefer the second method.

Answer (score 2):

ActionEvent in actionPerformed() will tell you the source of the button pressed. So you can do one of two things, you can name the button (which is not the same as the button text) something indicative of the room, or you can provide a command string that the button invokes, which is also available from the ActionEvent.

Check out the [JButton JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), it has links to dealing with Actions and specifically button Actions supported.

It will focus your question a little better as well, since you'll have a better idea of how you're looking to achieve your goal.